# why do my divs drop down below where they should be?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, responsive

I'm trying to develop a new layout for a page on my site, and admittedly it's ambitious, considering my skill level. Below is a link to what I've achieved so far, but I'm having this issue that when you click on the project boxes below the Welcome line, it does everything I expect, except to stay level with the other resized divs. You'll see what I mean if you try it.

http://flightsimsoc.co.uk/indexTest.php

I'm not using any complex javascript here, (in fact my method is pretty poor and inefficient, but largely just a stand in until I learn more and can achieve the same effect with less code), it's just a bunch of lines editing the styles of the divs. So I'm thinking the problem is obviously the css - this problem has been bugging me for the last week or so now, so I'm just thinking if anyone's got time to have a look, two heads are better than one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First, welcome to SO! Unfortunetely we're unable to help you solve the issue because your question lacks [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44662428/edit) your question and provide us with any _relevant_ code you have so far.

Comment: You need to add `vertical-align: top;` to your `.projectBoxes` rule. Still, please don't make us dig through tons of code like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    .projectBoxes {
       vertical-align: top;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to shrink a box down to 3% width while the content within that is still attempting to fit inside it. You need to add an overflow to your project boxes to make it not spill out when you shrink it down.

```
.projectBoxes {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 20.5vh;
    color: #222;
    transition: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Should probably also visually hide the content in the collapsed boxes so they don't show when collapsed assuming that is the desired effect.

Comment: ah, thanks! Didn't know about this -  sorry for the lack of decent presentation, I'll try and make it a little more accessible next time.

Also, is the content of the reduced boxes not disappearing for you?

Comment: It is disappearing, but depending on what you do in there the way it is coded to me seems like there is potential for issue.